# d3 append and enter issues

Tags: d3.js, svg

So I am having a problem when following a very simple d3 tutorial. Essentially I am attempting to add SVG circle elements by binding data to the current svg circle elements then calling enter.append As shown below:

```
var svg =d3.select("body").selectAll("svg");
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");
var w=window.innerWidth;
console.log(circle);
circle.data([500,57,112,200,600,1000]);


circle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cy",function(d) {
        return (d)
        })
    .attr("cx", function(i){
        return (i*100)
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d);
        })
```

Which seems like it would add 3 new circle elements (because I already have 3 created). However, instead of getting these 3 new circle elements added, I am running into this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object SVGCircleElement],[objectSVGCircleElement],[object SVGCircleElement] has no method 'enter'

I have done essentially the same thing with paragraphs, and it seems to work fine:

```
var p =d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
.data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
.text(function(d) { return "I'm number " + d + "!"; });

 //Enter    
 p.enter().append("p")
.text(function(d) { return "I'm number " + d + "!"; })
.style("color", function(d, i) {
 return i % 2 ? "#000" : "#eee";
});
```

However as soon as I try to add SVG Elements into it, I continue to get the same error.

It seems like there should be just a syntax error or something, but I have gone through the code 5 trillion times, and can't find anything.

Any help is much appreciated, and thank you before hand for your time.

Isaac

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to call `enter` on the result of `circle.data` instead of `circle` itself.

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");
circle.data([500,57,112,200,600,1000]).enter().append("circle");
```

You did this correctly in your `p` example by storing the return of `data` in the `p` variable. Whereas in your `circle` example, you are storing the return of `d3.select.selectAll` in your `circle` variable.

Comment: Thanks so much! that gets rid of my error, and makes perfect sense. You've saved me twice already Mr. Olsen!

Comment: @IsaacCohen No problem. Please accept the answer if there are no other issues with this question.

Comment: sorry that took so long, Tried to accept it, but it wouldn't let me for an hour then got distracted and forgot about it. My apologies!